# Multiple image processing, on custom post type in Wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I have developed custom post type in Wordpress, and besides other I am trying to process and display images on every post page.

When I set multiple image html fields, ie

```
<input type="file" name="an_uploaded_attachment" id="multiUpload" />
<input type="file" name="an_uploaded_attachment" id="multiUpload" />
```

and submit post, images are normaly displayed on post page. But when I include mutiple file upload like

```
<input type="file" name="an_uploaded_attachment" id="multiUpload" multiple />
```

images are not processed.

This is what I am using for registering images in WP:

```
 if (!function_exists('wp_generate_attachment_metadata')){

            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/image.php');

            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/file.php');

            require_once(ABSPATH . "wp-admin" . '/includes/media.php');

        }


         //if ($_FILES) {

            foreach ($_FILES as $file => $array) {

                if ($_FILES[$file]['error'] !== UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {

                    return "upload error : " . $_FILES[$file]['error'];

                }

                $attach_id = media_handle_upload( $file, $post_id );
                update_post_meta($post_id,'_thumbnail_id',$attach_id);

            }
```

Does anyone knows something about this? Tried few scripts but they dont work.

Comment: WordPress version? This stuff changed at 3.5.

Comment: tried this http://wordpress.stackexchange.com/questions/45188/front-end-post-with-multiple-upload-images 

aint working